# How to make a node sticky only in a given Taxonomy Term?

Tags: views, theming, taxonomy-terms

Content Type: Book (with Field: Term Reference->Subject)

Hierarchical Taxonomy: Subjects

```
Science
--Chemistry
--Maths
--Biology
Engineering
--Civil
--Electrical
```

When I create a node (Intro to Maths) I mark them under taxonomy terms relevant to the subject(Chemistry, Maths, Civil, Electrical).

Now I use [Nice Taxonomy Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/nice_taxonomy_menu) to display a collapsible list of taxonomy terms in the sidebar. When a user clicks on a taxonomy term they will see a list of books in alphabetical order, categorized under that subject.

But for some nodes (Intro to Maths) are more important to one subject than others. So for tax term Maths, Intro to Maths should display at the top of the list (disregarding the alphabetical order).

I tried marking the nodes with *Sticky at top of lists*, but that will place that node at the top of the list in every subject it's associated with it. I don't want that. I just want it to be at the top only for one subject(Maths) and for other subjects(Chemistry, Civil, Electrical) the location it gets according to the alphabetical order.

My second approach is to create an additional term reference field called *Important Subjects* and mark only the subject that I need the node to appear at the top(Maths). I'm trying to add some logic at the template level with no success.

To complicate the matter further, since I'm using Nice Taxonomy Menu, I have to stick with the view (but can modify this view) that they provide with the module.

Any help appreciated. Thanks